# How badly do space filling curves fail to be injective?

Tags: general-topology

Is it possible to have a space filling curve with finite fibers? To what extent can we control the failure of space filling curves to be injective?

Comment: @tomasz : "continuous" !!  Too many hours grading exams.  I should probably not do math right now.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I have a hunch that a continuous curve with finite fibres will be a local homeomorphism, which should imply that the image has empty interior.

Comment: Define space filling curve? A continuous map from $\Bbb R$ onto $\Bbb R^n$, e.g.?

Comment: The classical Peano curve has finite multiplicity (preimage of each point has cardinality at most 4).

Comment: @tomasz That would be wrong

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I was thinking $[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$, but any $1$-Hausdorff-dimensional onto any $2$-Hausdorff-dimensional space would count imo.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That is interesting, thank you.